How to check what Powershell distribution channels are available?
Powershell check and imports the content of the poorly documented POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL environment variable.
On a Windows-11 Pro, installation the value is shown as:
# $Env:POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL

MSI:Windows 10 Home


Why is the value shown wrong?
How can I list what distribution channels are available?
Where can they be found?
How can they be used?

